# can I use wand API in python without installing ImageMagick?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I  used wand API of ImageMagick in python for ML project ,I want to change my coding file into one executable file so that I can share it to my friends but I got lots of difficulties to pack ImageMagick in one executable file, that's why I want to use wand without ImageMagick.
if you Answer this, then it will help me a lot.

Thankyou.  I

Comment: No. Wand uses Python's ctypes module to integrate with the C-API. Without ImageMagick's shared libraries existing on the host system, nothing will work.

Comment: Ok , but how do I package Imagemagick with my python script.